Problems with cache control directives?
I have just purchased Cloudflare Automatic Platform Optimization for WordPress to make my WP website work faster and more reliable with Cloudflare but despite that I keep on getting the same errors from Site Health status:
"Page cache is detected by looking for an active page cache plugin as well as making three requests to the homepage and looking for one or more of the following HTTP client caching response headers:
cache-control, expires, age, last-modified, etag, x-cache-enabled, x-cache-disabled, x-srcache-store-status, x-srcache-fetch-status.
Median server response time was 953 milliseconds. It should be less than the recommended 600 milliseconds threshold.
There was 1 client caching response header detected: x-cache-enabled.
A page cache plugin was detected."

Admittedly I am not an expert (at all!) but I am not sure what to do to modify these parameters in Cloudflare or if I did the right thing to purchase the APOW now as nothing has changed.
Can anybody shed some light, please as I feel stuck with something I do not if it works or if it’s right for me.
I’ve just read this are cache control directives? and I should adjust it all with cache rules or create a php file. Is that correct? If is so which values are correct for any of them (I can’t seem to find a straight answer anywhere).
My website is crystalhealinglondon.com.
Thank you so much for your help
I've read several articles but I can't seem to find how to modify or include this directives in Cloudflare or elsewhere.  Also I can't find which values I am supposed to give to them.
I thought that purchasing the Optimisation for WP on Cloudflare will take care of it.
